# How to combine two data frame, one with less values than the other by unique rowID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe. One is the output dataset.The other one is the original dataset. Since the output dataset is preprocessed; outliers and NA values are removed, this has gotten rid of rowID's in the dataset, and hence has lesser values. I am trying to output the classfier to the original dataset from the output dataset. However I am always getting an error.  Any suggestions as to how can I append the classifier values with the corresponding rowID to the original dataset.

Thank you.

My code.

```
predictions=clf_A.predict(data_test)

df = pd.read_csv("/Documents/TestingSet(4) (4).csv")

for i in range(0,len(df)):
    if(df['row ID'][i]==data_test['row ID'][i])
    df['QUALIFIED'][i] = predictions[i]


df.to_csv("TestingSet(4) (4).csv", index=False)

//df-Original dataSet
//data_set=output dataset with my classifier predictions
```

Comment: Can you add some data samples?

Comment: have you tried `merge`

Comment: But one idea - try `df.merge(pd.DataFrame(predictions, index=data_test.index), on='row ID', how='left')`

Comment: Or `df['QUALIFIED'] = df['row ID'].map(pd.Series(predictions, index=data_test.index))`

Comment: I did not try merge. I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: @ShadmanMahmood - So `merge` or `map` from comments above not working? If not, please add some [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Or try `data_test['QUALIFIED'] = predictions`
`df.merge(data_test[['row ID','QUALIFIED']], on='row ID', how='left')`

Comment: thank you sir, I will try and let you know

Comment: i recommend you should learn basic syntax of python first. about commenting and if loop. which is wrong in your post

Comment: "['row ID'] not in index" I donot know why this error is coming up

Comment: @jezrael ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index, Since the dataset has more SSL values than the original

Comment: @ShadmanMahmood - OK, is possible create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?